# Replacing disk IO waiting time with CPU computation time, is it a good practice?

Tags: performance, io, compression, cpu

Basically I have an application that reads and writes a lot (around 100k readings and 5K writings) of small files (around 50kb each) into the drive.

The machine that runs it have a pretty low CPU usage along with a 20/30% of iowait time on average.

I think that I can improve  the performance of my application by compressing those files before writing them into the drive, I'll save around 40kb for each file at the cost of a few milliseconds needed for the compression and decompression process.

Is this a good practice for speed things up in my example case?

Comment: Isn't that already provided by your operating system?  Btrfs on Linux, NTFS on Windows provide transparent file compression implemented by the file system.

Comment: I didn't know about this, anyway I'm working on an ext4 file system.

Comment: Not possible to give an general answer for all possible cases. Run a performance benchmark using different file sizes and see what difference it makes.

Comment: depends on your scenario - are you making synchronous calls to IO? if yes, have you considered going async?